# Deriving Isosensitivity Functions in ROC space from elementary signal detection parameters

Tags: probability, reference-request, signal-processing

In signal detection, an observer is assigned the task of discerning the presence (or absence) of some signal with accompanying noise. There are four possible outcomes: a hit ($H$), a miss, a false alarm ($FA$), or a correct rejection. An iso-sensitivity function is the function that describes the relation between correct and false reports of a difference, with $P(H)$ on the $y$-axis and $P(FA)$ on the $x$-axis.

If $P(H) = p + (1-p)P(FA)$

and $P(FA) = g$  (guess)

and $p$, $g$ both lie between $0$ and $1$,

can someone walk me through how to derive the prediction for the iso-sensitivity function in ROC space? (Or point me to some source that can clearly explain this)?

Comment: Man, that's confusing. $p$ is both a parameter (probability?) and a function...

Comment: I don't seem to understand the question. The ROC function is just $f(g) = p + (1-p)g$, 
 where $g$ is the false alarm rate, no?